# Get a file from a directory in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file

I have been doing research on how to get a file out of directory using php/Laravel and nothing seems to be working.

I am running a command: `app/commands/commandfile.php` and I am trying to get a `PNG` file out of my directory: `app/storage/resources/icon.png`. Well I have tried several methods:

`Storage::url('storage/resources/icon.png')` and `asset('storage/resources/')`

But nothing seems to work. Can someone help me out?

If you are curious why I need this file. I am calling a notification system: `php-fcm` and trying to set the notification icon:

`$note = new Notification('Catalyst', $message);
        $note->setColor('#ffffff')
            ->setBadge(1)
        ->setIcon(`

Thanks!

Comment: create a sym link php artisan storage:link

Comment: I tried that and got this in return: `There are no commands defined in the "storage" namespace`

Comment: Are you in the root folder of your project? Actually, you may be using an older version than that which the command exsits.

Comment: I am in `app/commands/commandfile.php`

Comment: Are you sure you are doing the right thing? FCM's icon field is supposed to be an name of the resource on your mobile app itself, not a URL to your server.

Comment: What if u test with `\Storage::get('resources/icon.png');`

Comment: Can you put the version of laravel you are using?